# How can I customize the selected tab indicator in a TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-touch-event

I would like to change the selected tab indicator of a TabLayout, with a custom icon, that should follow the same behavior (as the user slides towards the next tab, the icon moves accordingly).

There's no default method in the class since you can only reach a tab's layout customization. I decided to take a look to the TabLayout's [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java), but 1) I can't find in the class the point in which there's the definition of the shape that the tab indicator will assume when drawn, and 2) I can't even fully import the class. 
I also would like – if possible – to avoid any third-party library, since the project is already very heavy.

Do you have any suggestions? I can see two possible approaches:

1. finding a way to customize the TabLayout class in order to
   replace the "squarish shape" with a custom icon.
2. finding a way to
   coordinate the user's touch gestures on the ViewPager with the
   movements of a custom View (ie. my icon).

Comment: That is exactly what I need too

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of at the moment is you'll have to create a custom view layout file that represents your desired "selected tab" and annotate `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` to your `TabLayout` in the XML file.

After that, you'll have to register a listener on the tablayout instance, and check which index is being selected, and with the given index, call `TabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(yourSelectedCustomView)`.

Take a look here on how to create a custom view for `TabLayout` : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48258731/4974461

Comment: will this also support animation of the sliding motion of the indicator?